# Add partial uniqueness constraint in postgres on a row such that one value is okay to duplicate

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, unique-constraint

I want to create a table of emails `emails` where all values in the "email" column must be unique except one for a "redacted@redacted.com" placeholder. Example:

- foo@gmail.com
- bar@gmail.com
- redacted@redacted.com
- zoo@gmail.com
- redacted@redacted.com
- hey@gmail.com
- redacted@redacted.com

I see in postgres documentation that it's straightforward to allow `null` values to be non-duplicative, but is there a way to do this with another value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_emails_email on (email)
    where email <> 'redacted@redacted.com';
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's an extrapolated version in case anyone is looking for a more generalized doc in the future. 


```create unique index <indexname> on <tablename> (<columnname>) where <columnname> <> <value>;```